# Two test in same document, Exam

Tags: exam

I'm using the exam class.

I'm making two tests in same document. Some questions are the same but some different. Is there a simple format I can use like "printanswers" and "noprintanswer" so test A or test B will be printed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do this. In the preambule, you put the following commands:

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\groupif}[3]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\groupnr}}{#2}{#3}}
\newcommand{\group}[2]{\groupif{#1}{#2}{}}

\def\groupnr{1}
```

If you have a question that needs to be different for each group, you can make different versions using the `\group` command:

```
\group1{\question How much is $2+2$?}
\group2{\question What is the multiple of $5$ and $6$?}

\question Compute the derivative of \group1{x^2}\group2{x^3}.
```

To change your document to the second version, you change `\def\groupnr{1}` to `\def\groupnr{2}`. This can be extended to having more groups, by including `\group3`, `group4` and so on.

Comment: Eventually you may get to the point where exam class is more of a obstacle than a help.